# Inequality for inner product with constraints.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

> Define 
>   $$\triangle := \ \{a\in
>  \mathbb{R}^{n} \ \ : \ \  \sum_{i=1}^n a_i=1, \ \ a_i\ge0 \ \ \forall_{1\le i \le n} \}$$ 
>   Moreover, let  $ \ L \ $  be any linear
>   subspace of  $ \ \mathbb{R}^{n}, \ $  and put
>   $$Q:= \ \ L \ \cap \
>  \triangle.$$ 
>   Prove that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$
>   \begin{equation}\sup_{p\in Q} \ x^{T}p \ \ \ge \ \
>  \inf\Big\{y^Tp \ \ : \ \ y^Tp_1=y^Tp_2 \ \ \forall_{p_1,p_2 \in Q}, \
>  \ y \ge x, \ p \in Q \Big\}. \tag{$\star$}\end{equation}

Note that  $ \ \inf \ $  is over  $ \ y \ $  such that $ \ y\ge x \ $ and $ \ f(p)=<y,p> \ $ is constant on $ \ Q \ $. Then $ \ y^Tp \ $ does not depend on choice of $ \ p\in Q \ $.

This problem comes from a problem in financial mathematics. This is the reformulation of this problem with probability and financial parts deleted. I believe that this should be an easy problem in linear programing, which I do not have experience in. I have been trying to solve it with basic linear algebra methods, but failed so far. I would be highly interested in such elementary solution. I would be very thankful for any help, insight or hints. This seems as an easy problem...

As a matter of fact, I even suspect that $(\star)$ should turn out to be an equality.

Comment: What have $p_1,p_2$ got do with it?

Comment: $y$ is such that function $f(p)=<y,p>$ is constant on $Q$.

Comment: Presumably the $p$ in the $\inf$ also ranges over $Q$?

Comment: $\inf$ is over $y$ such that $y\ge x$ and $f(p)=<y,p>$ is constant on $Q$. Then $y^Tp$ does not depend on choice of $p\in Q$. I will try to rewrite my question in more clear way.

Comment: Do you mean to have $p \in Q$ in the $\inf$?

Comment: Yes, p is in Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I have found my answer.  This is a relatively easy problem, if we know Farkass' lemma:

> Let $ \ A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n} \ $ and $ \ b\in \mathbb{R}^{m} \ $. Then exactly one of the following statements is true:
>
> 1. There exists $ \ y\in \mathbb{R}^{n} \ $ such that $ \ Ay=b \ $ and $ \ y\ge 0, \ $
> 2. There exists $ \ z\in \mathbb{R}^{m} \ $ such that $ \ A^Tz \ge 0 \ $ and $ \ b^Tz <0 \ $ and $\ z \ \ge 0, \ $
>
> where $\ x \ \ge \ 0$ means that all components of the vector $ \ x \ $  are nonnegative.

Farkas' lemma turns out to be quite important in proving basic duality results in linear programming. I think, that applying this lemma is the most elementary way of solving my problem.